# How to sort odd number list using only merge sort algorithm? and also even number separately?

Tags: mergesort

How to sort odd  number list using only merge sort algorithm? and also even number separately?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on what you mean by "odd number list" and "even number separately?" For example, could you show an example of an input and an output, along with what you've tried so far?

Comment: let assume i have a  list like 99,87,47,111,10,144,40,59 and i only want to sort odd numbers and skip the even numbers.

Comment: What would the result of the sorting algorithm be on that list? Do you want to keep the odd numbers in the same relative positions and just reorder them? Or put the odd numbers first before the even numbers? Or something else?